# How do I encrypt my table column in Grails?

Tags: mysql, grails

I have been doing this way to encrypt my column in mysql table :

```
INSERT INTO credit_card_info (card_id, card_num) VALUES (UUID() , AES_ENCRYPT(${params.card_num_enc},'*************'))
```

And for decryption I just used `AES_DECRYPT` method instead. Now I shifted to using GORM.

I want to achieve the same effect with GORM. Is that possible, that in domain class I can specify the encrypt technique? Is so how do I decrypt them in back? And is that possible to use `UUID` function in GORM?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512196/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-columns-in-a-grails-domain-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spring-security-core plugin](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) does a similar task for encrypting user's passwords before saving.

[GORM Domain objects have events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) that can be fired before insert, after load etc which would allow you to encrypt/decrypt the data.